# NoMethodError while I defined it using metaprogramming

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am working on some code. I am trying to print a list of sample colors using a gem that I created and it throws a `NoMethodError`
I am opening the String class and I am doing that.

```
def self.sample_colors
  @@colors_arr.each do |color|
    puts "This is #{color}".color
  end
end
```

It is supposed to be working because `.color` should change to ever color the array has so, first loop would be `.red` then `.blue` and so on.
This code is taking care of creating the method for each color.

```
def self.create_colors
  @@colors_arr.zip(@@color_codes).each do |color,code|
    self.send(:define_method,color) do
    "\e[#{code}m#{self}\e[0m"
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?
Edit: If I use `.red` or `.blue` it works, I just don't get why that works and this one isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with

> puts "This is #{color}"**.color**

You are basically calling a method **color** every time. Ruby does not care about the fact you have a local variable called color.

You want to define sample_colors as:

```
def self.sample_colors
  @@colors_arr.each do |color|
    puts "This is #{color}".send(color)
  end
end
```

The send method will call the method name represented by a given string/symbol on the object.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck here like, for an hour.

Comment: As a best practice you should use `public_send` instead of `send`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method `color` instead of the color's name. Try this:

```
puts "This is #{color}".send(color.to_sym)
```